# Copyobj in Scilab

Tags: user-interface, copy, scilab, uicontrol

I am working on a GUI in Scilab.
As I know from Matlab, I can copy an object with copyobj().
Is there also a command like this in Scilab?

What I wanted to do is, just to copy a listbox from one figure into another one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [copy](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.1/en_US/copy.html)

```
listbox_new = copy(listbox_old)
set(listbox_new,'parent',new_figure_handle)
// or
copy(listbox_old,new_axes_handles)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response!
I tried it our, but an error occured:

load: Unable to load 'C:\Users\LD777~1.MIT\AppData\Local\Temp\SC0353~1\SCI7F0C.tmp'

Do you if it is because copy is just for graphic entities?

Comment: Reading the help, it is